# Accessible change menu item for navigation using unobtrusive JS, not jQuery,

Tags: javascript, css, html, accessibility, semantics

I'm feeling like a serious id10t right now, but I have spent a week looking for a Semantic, Accessible, JavaScript method of keeping an active style on a link until **another** link is clicked on. I hoped it would be pretty basic stuff...

The site is a single page with anchor links to various sections on the page using id/anchor tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="UTF-8" /></head>
<body>

<header>
<h1>Crown Cattle Company</h1>
<ol>
<li><a href="../index.html">(Temp Home)</a></li>
<li><a href="#farm">Orielton</a></li>
<li><a href="#genetics">Wagyu</a></li>
<li><a href="#cooking">Recipes</a></li>
</ol>
</header>

<main>
<article>

<section id="orielton">
<h2>Orielton</h2>
<nav><ul>
<li><a href="#farm">Crown Cattle Company</a></li>
<li><a href="#maps">Map</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul></nav>
<p id="farm">CCC. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p id="map"><div id="map-canvas"></div></p>
<p id="contact">Contact. There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
</section>
</article>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

The source file is here:
(http://www.crowncattle.com.au/html/content%20scroll.html#farm)

Thanking you in advance for keeping me sane. This is doing my head in. Cheers

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. Is this what you need: `document.getElementById('linkID').focus();` ?

Comment: I suspect it's my fault. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In an up-to-date browser, I'd suggest:

```
function lastLink(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _lastClicked = document.querySelector('a.lastActive');
    if (_lastClicked) {
        _lastClicked.classList.remove('lastActive');
    }
    this.classList.add('lastActive');
}

var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

[].forEach.call(links, function(a){
    a.addEventListener('click', lastLink);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2jf3G/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
- [`eventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: Hi David, is there any way to incorporate the <nav> tag so my ordinary links aren't changed too? Thanks for your time. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is to make a link active, you can use this:

```
document.getElementById('linkID').focus();
```

When you click on another link, that link will become focused, and the original link will lose focus.

---

**Step by step guide**:

If you have this HTML:

```
<a href="http://whoknows.com">A Link</a>
```

You need to add an ID to it - unless it already has one. An ID should be unique per page. Here, I have used "linkID":

```
<a href="http://whoknows.com" id="linkID">A Link</a>
```

Then, you need to add this script to your HTML, below the link:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('linkID').focus();
</script>
```

Comment: That looks perfect, but I'm having a brain freeze, could you flesh that out a bit? Much appreciated!

Comment: @HMR - Is this the kind of fleshing you need?

Comment: Thanks for your response. One prob though, html only allows one instance of id="linkID" per page. Can this be done using class instead of id? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. The easiest way is with `document.getElementsByClassName("linkClass")[0]` - But it won't work in older browsers

Comment: Cheers! I'm aiming for graceful degradation, so hopefully it won't matter for the older browsers.